# Convert unsigned char array with int to unsigned char

Tags: c++

Can somebody help me out with below error. Shall I cast `len` before I try to pass `buf`?

```
int len=2;
unsigned char tmp[len + 1];
unsigned char * buf = &tmp;
```

The error is:

```
error: cannot convert 'unsigned char (*)[(((unsigned int)((int)len)) + 1)]' to 'unsigned char*' in assignment
```

Comment: array internal representation is as a pointer. That is in your case type of tmp is unsigned char * and type of buf is unsigned char *.So type miss match you try to assign char ** to char *.

Comment: @Rajesh: **Arrays are _not_ pointers.** The type of `tmp` is `unsigned char[3]`. Nothing else. There is no `unsigned char**` here anywhere, and certainly no `char**`.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit:sorry for forgetting to add constant pointer (pointer value can not be changed) which points to a fixed memory location only. But I explain it only for type miss match Nothing else.

Comment: @Rajesh: The type mismatch is between `unsigned char*` (pointer to an `unsigned char`) and `unsigned char(*)[3]` (pointer to an array of three `unsigned chars`), not between `unsigned char*` and `unsigned char**`. Note that I _do_ ignore the VLA component and pretend that the array dimension is fixed at `3`, as it's supposed to be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : I don't for c++ I say all above things(type mismatch according to error highlighted ) . And error come only for the use of '&' address of operator only. This discussion can go to a bit longer but user may divert and confuse also. and I provide the simplest answer to the problem. You can ans this in a longer way.

Comment: @Rajesh: I choose to answer it in the correct way.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a pointer to the array, use

```
unsigned char * buf = tmp;
```

By the way, the way you declare `tmp` makes it a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA). Technically, [these are not allowed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c), although many compilers support VLAs as an extension.

Comment: Also to allow it to compile, len must be declared as const.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `len`. The problem is that you are trying to take the address of the array, rather than the address of the first element of the array; the types simply don't match.

Instead:

```
unsigned char* buf = &tmp[0];
```

Also, the array name conveniently (FSVO "conveniently") decays to `&tmp[0]` anyway, so you could write simply:

```
unsigned char* buf = tmp;
```

In addition you are presently not using a constant value for the array's dimension — ensure that `len` is made `const` and initialised with a constant value. In C++11, this'd better be `constexpr` to *really* ensure that you're not accidentally attempting to use GCC VLAs.

Comment: Ooh, what case does C++11 break so that you have to add `constexpr` rather than just having a `const` int with a visible initializer that's an ICE?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm not aware of any, but surely `constexpr` is preferable by its nature? If you always ensure you have a visible initializer then great, but asking the OP to remember to do this seems like a bit of a reach. No offence, OP.

Comment: ah, I was concentrating on "really ensure" rather than "better". I thought you meant that `const int` in C++11 doesn't really ensure that. AFAIK you're right that `constexpr` is a better way of expressing it in C++11.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I meant rather that using `const int` -- and just hoping that you remembered everything else you need -- doesn't ensure that. ;)

Comment: Yes, it makes a bigger difference with `const int a = foo();` where `foo()` may or may not be a `constexpr` function. `constexpr int a = foo();` checks that it is. With `const int a = 4;` I'm reasonably confident I can verify by eye that `4` is a constant ;-)